# Можно ли использовать библиотеки LWJGL в проекте libJDX?

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, libgdx, lwjgl

Буду разрабатывать игру, и у меня появился вопрос по поводу **libJDX** и **LWJGL**. Можно ли использовать библиотеки **LWJGL** в проекте **libJDX**?

Comment: libGDX??? Да можно, но непонятно зачем. Зачем брать движок и при этом использовать параллельно низкоуровневую библиотеку

Answer (score 0):

LWJGL3 используется в ligGDX в качестве бэкенда для десктопа.

По сути, когда мы собираем проект для декстопной версии для работы с графикой используется библиотека LWJGL3 по-умолчанию. Можно сказать, libGDX - это более высокий уровень абстракции.

Можно ли добраться до LWJGL3? Да (com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.*). Надо ли это делать - нет. Как минимум по тому, что это будет код только под ПК.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/810101)

Comment: Не понимаю, что ожидается в качестве ответа. По сути, когда мы собираем проект для декстопной версии для работы с графикой используется библиотека LWJGL3 по-умолчанию. Можно сказать, libGDX - это более высокий уровень абстракции. 

Можно ли добраться до LWJGL3? Да (com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.*).
Надо ли это делать - нет. Как минимум по тому, что это будет код только под ПК.

Comment: @КириллНовгородцев, в _комментарии_ вы дали больше информации чем в ответе :)